# ray tracing: horizontal artifacts with Area lights

Tags: graphics, raytracing

Hi what is the cause of these horizontal lines?? The area light is the yellow square above the green plane. The pattern of lines changes depending on the distance of area light above the plane but they are still horizontal lines.

I have 4 point light sources uniformly distributed over the surface of area light (yellow square patch).

You can see what it looks like [here](https://imageshack.com/i/5mhuryp) (16x supersampling).

Comment: Looks like shadow acne (A.K.A. incorrect self shadowing). 

Are you doing something to avoid shadow rays intersect with the surface originating them ? 

You can offset your shadow ray's origin using surface normal or checking that the intersected shape is different than the one originating the ray.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like shadow acne:  undesired self-shadowing, patterned due to approximation errors.  Note that the lines are absent from the fully shadowed areas, which suggests the problem is that shadowing system incorrectly "thinks" the green plane is in shadow there.

Edit: since you are ray tracing, the problem may be that you are wrongly intersecting the outgoing shadow rays from the plane that "emitted" them.  The following suggestions apply to rasterization with shadow maps, not ray tracing, but they may still be instructive...

---

Shadow mapping works by first drawing a depth map from the point of view of each light, recording a "shadow map" of shadowing objects.  Then, when drawing the actual image, each pixel samples the shadowing depth from the shadow map, and compares it to the computed depth from that light of the pixel location:  if the pixel depth is greater than the shadow depth, it is shadowed.

Note that, if the object being drawn *is* the closest shadowing object to the light, the pixel depth should be *the same* as the shadow depth.  However, because the sampling and floating point calculations are not exact, the comparison is only *approximately* equal.  So, part of the time (based on the whims of sampling and floating point error), it thinks the pixel depth is farther than the shadow depth caused by the same object:  the object shadows itself.

---

There are several ways to avoid shadow acne.  The simplest option (and the obvious choice for your scene) is to remove the object from the list of shadow-casters.  Since your plane appears to be intended as a "floor", it is not supposed to shadow anything, anyway.  This has the additional advantage of saving the time it would otherwise take to draw your floor onto all your shadow maps...

By the same principle, if an object is "watertight", with one-sided triangles consistently facing outwards, you should reverse the triangle orientation test for the shadow maps.  This will take the shadow depths from the dark side of the object (which is in full shadow anyway because it faces away from the light), so it won't cause acne on the bright side.

If you have a flat object which must be visible from both sides, you can apply a bias to the shadow depth;  graphics software and hardware typically has provisions for this.  Unfortunately, this can be a bit fiddly:  the bias must be large enough to hide the sampling/computation error, but small enough that it doesn't cause other artifacts.